# Omnipay: Transfering money form PayPal account to Stripe account

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, stripe-payments, omnipay

I am creating a laravel project where I am using omnipay. I have never used omnipay before but what I know is that one can transfer money between two accounts (e.g. PayPal). However, my question is, is it possible to transfer money between two accounts of a different provider. For example: The customer is paying with PayPal but I want that money transfered directly to my Stripe acocunt. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not supported. There would need to be an external account of some sort as an intermediary.